# Spring-MVC: Multiple controllers for one request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to show output of several controllers on one page.

```
Menu controller: adds "menuItems" collection to the model
Banner controller: adds "banner" to the  model
ListItems controller: the "main" one: it adds all other data to display
```

My view (I use xslt) knows about model and works with it.

My question is how to call *3* controllers for one request and combine their output to the one model.

I do not want to use inheritance here (that smells). I do not want to use interceptors because they are low-level and I want to work with mapped parameters instead of request and response.

How that could be implemented in spring MVC?

Thanks!

PS: I will try to use WebRequestInterceptor probably

Comment: Call the necessary methods from the ListItems controller?

Comment: And what if I have 20 controllers?

Comment: Add a catch-all controller and use listeners to modify the view?

Comment: looks like a use for decorator or chain of responsibility patterns, if you don't use inheritance then you will use composition from the main controller - it's not possible to guess what configurations of controllers are possible(it's not even shown how are they mapped) so it's hard to answer. it's not Spring responsibility to implement this anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can use Handler interceptor feature of spring mvc, i have used this for menu,breadcrumb etc. you can find more for implementation [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/)